# Installing Win8 in VHD: "could not load \Windows\system32\winload.exe"

Tags: windows-8-preview

I'm trying the install Win8 in a VHD using the [Hanselman Guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx)

All went well until the PC rebooted and Windows shows me this error:

```
Your PC needs to be repaired

The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because
a required file is missing or contains errors.

File:\windows\system32\winload.exe
Error code: 0xc000000e
```

[image]

**Ideas?**

Comment: Perhaps your install source or target disk is corrupted, have you check them, and/or tried the install more than once? Is the VHD located on an internal drive?

Comment: Also, have you tried repairing the boot records/sector? ([Bootrec.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392))

Comment: Yes, tried two times, same result. VHD in internal drive

Comment: Haven't tried with Bootrec. How?

Comment: Tried Bootrec /fixMbr and /fixBoot. Both ok. But /rebuildbcd says: total windows installations: 0. Is that a bad thing?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem, and I fixed it by moving the VHD to my C drive.

Comment: Too bad, because my C: is a SSD with almost no free space.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0xc000000e is `STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE`, which is a bit sad. `\system32\winload.exe` is the first file loaded off the disk (it runs the preboot environement before `\system\ntoskrnl.exe` is loaded which is the first bit that anyone would recognise as Windows), so this looks like something in the filesystem driver is objecting to how your virtual machine is representing your virtual disk to the OS (i.e Windows doesn't like the virtual hard disk controller).

Has Windows 8 ever successfully booted up on that Virtual machine before? If not - it may be that the particular virtual machine software you are using isn't supported by the Windows 8 Preview, in which case your best bet is to go and use a different VM software.

If you have booted up on that VM before, this looks like something has gone badly wrong and you might need to reinstall the OS.

Comment: Never successfully booted from the VHD before. It's like the hardware cant find the VHD or the VHD does not "stick" in the boot configuration (or something)

Comment: In which case it's most likely that this is just Windows8 not being fully supported by your virtual machine software. Windows8 is best run on Microsoft's Hypervisor VM (which is what they use to test internally and the only one that Microsoft guarantees will work), otherwise VMware workstation are probably your best bet.

Comment: I'm not running any VM software, I'm only virtualizing the hard disk.

Comment: So you're doing a boot-from-VHD from a Windows8 install on bare metal? In which case this is a bug in Win8, file a bug with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you first compare the hash on your ISO.

MD5: cda63e335fb9af5354c63441f5aa5169
SHA1: 1288519c5035bcac83cbfa23a33038ccf5522749

Worse comes to worse, try a reinstall.
Personally, I've run the Dev preview off VHDs.  Haven't had time to try this one.

Comment: The hash are ok

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same error, but under different circumstances than you.

In my case I was moving existing vhdx file to a new path (actually new drive). To continue native booting into it I had to edit boot records in BCD to point to the new path. There is official guide for this scenario, but it is missing one critical command - which may help you.

**The official guide**

The official guide [Add a Native-Boot Virtual Hard Disk to the Boot Menu](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799299) can be summarized as:

```
:: Add boot record by copying and modifying current record
:: This command gives you new {new-guid} you will use below
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Description here"

:: Update copied record with the new path N:\windows.vhdx
bcdedit /set {new-guid} device vhd=[N:]\windows.vhdx
bcdedit /set {new-guid} osdevice vhd=[N:]\windows.vhdx
```

Fairly easy, but it didn't work; I was getting the same error as you.

**The fix**

To fix it I had to mount the vhdx from its new path `N:\windows.vhdx` to disk letter `O:\` and run this command:

```
:: bcdboot does two things:
:: a) it creates or repairs boot files in specified location
:: b) it creates or updates boot record in BCD
bcdboot O:\Windows
```

Then you can unmount the vhdx. It didn't really made huge difference in `bcdedit /v` listing -- basically it just updated the copied boot record with a new guid instead of previous `{new-guid}` -- but something got fixed in the boot records behind the curtain and it started working.

*Note: you could argue that `bcdboot` actually fixed the vhdx file, namely the boot files in `O:\`, but that could not play role in my scenario, because I discarded the vhdx I ran the `bcdboot` on and instead used another copy that was never treated this way.*